# 1980s sci-fi anime where a guy with longish brown hair (and possibly wearing a cape) is fatally injured by a robot which looks similar to a Dalek

Tags: story-identification, anime, telepathy

The only thing I remember about this anime I watched on a VHS player during the 1980s (unfortunately can't remember the exact year), is a scene which involves a robot which looked similar to a Dalek (you know, like the ones who appear in the *Dr. Who* TV series) which injures a guy (I think he had long -but not very long- brown hair, and he was wearing a cape, although I'm not too sure about the cape) with two mechanical spikes that came out of the robot's body (pulled in after the injury).

While the robot is leaving and the guy is dying, the latter sends a message to another guy (who watched the whole thing, and was hiding in the hallway) with telepathy, while holding his hand.